# Specify specific shapes in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a DCA plot which I have told ggplot2 to give different shapes to based on which site they have come from. I want to fill it with a different variable so I need shapes 15-25. How do I tell ggplot2 to pick symbols that are "fillable"? I am currently having to use `colour=regforamcountsall$SWLI` but I am aware this will change to `fill` once I can use the correct symbols.

```
library(vegan)
library(ggplot2)
library(cluster)
library(ggfortify)
library(factoextra)

regforamcountsall<-read.csv("regionalforamscountsall.csv",header=TRUE)


regforamcountsall$Sample = NULL
regforamcountsall$Site=NULL
regforamcountsall$SWLI=NULL



#Run DCA
ord <- decorana(regforamcountsall)

plot(ord)

#use this summary code to get species scores for DCA1 and DCA2

summary(ord)

#put species scores values in from ord plot summary stats 
species.scores<-read.csv("speciesscores.csv")


species.scores$species <- row.names(species.scores)

#Using the scores function from vegan to extract the sample scores and convert to a data.frame
data.scores <- as.data.frame(scores(ord))  

# create a column of groupings/clusters, from the rownames of data.scores
data.scores$endgroup <- as.factor(pam(regforamcountsall, 3)$clustering) 

#getting the convex hull of each unique point set
find_hull <- function(df) df[chull(data.scores$DCA1, data.scores$DCA2), ]
hulls <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(unique(data.scores$endgroup))){
  endgroup_coords <- data.scores[data.scores$endgroup == i,]
  hull_coords <- data.frame(
    endgroup_coords[chull(endgroup_coords[endgroup_coords$endgroup == i,]$DCA1,
                          endgroup_coords[endgroup_coords$endgroup == i,]$DCA2),])
  hulls <- rbind(hulls,hull_coords)
}


data.scores$numbers <- 1:length(data.scores$endgroup)

regforamcountsall<-read.csv("regionalforamscountsall.csv",header=TRUE)

#DCA 
dca <- ggplot() + 
  # add the point markers
geom_point(data=data.scores,aes(x=DCA1,y=DCA2,colour=regforamcountsall$SWLI),size=4,pch=regforamcountsall$Site) +
  geom_point(data=species.scores,aes(x=DCA1,y=DCA2),size=4,pch=18,colour="grey22", alpha=0.8) +
  # add the hulls and labels - numbers position labels
  geom_polygon(data = hulls,aes(x=DCA1,y=DCA2,fill=endgroup), alpha = 0.25) +
  #geom_text(data=data.scores,aes(x=DCA1-0.03,y=DCA2,colour=endgroup, label = numbers))+
  geom_text(data=species.scores,aes(x=DCA1+0.1,y=DCA2+0.1, label = species))+
  theme_classic()+
  
dca

structure(list(species = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), DCA1 = c(-2.1171, 
-1.6729, -2.0028, -0.961, 1.0481, -0.3297), DCA2 = c(0.3289, 
-0.839, 0.343, -0.36, 1.9886, 0.9175)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

structure(list(DCA1 = c(-1.13413767300063, -1.71882459720626, 
-1.52607134864953, -1.32194095756686, -1.69520357242868, -0.141922349857954
), DCA2 = c(0.0633645085805346, 0.377157525612764, 0.120142668154026, 
0.174188452426213, -0.00943018635973858, 0.326711919777559), 
    DCA3 = c(0.00488308715045149, -0.749294000660211, -0.480312621168478, 
    -0.170111605941518, 0.0943798426120048, 0.0441643135499474
    ), DCA4 = c(-0.35705788574092, -0.475715464243968, -0.350994520702336, 
    -0.257048075477532, 0.0210812333627229, 0.0754508519926794
    ), endgroup = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3"), class = "factor"), numbers = 1:6), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

structure(list(Sample = structure(c(2L, 23L, 30L, 24L, 25L, 28L
), .Label = c("LG1", "LG120", "LG130", "LG135", "LG160", "LG170", 
"LG185", "LG2", "LG225", "LG230", "LG240", "LG245", "LG255", 
"LG260", "LG275", "LG280", "LG285", "LG290", "LG295", "LG3", 
"LG305", "LG315", "LG32", "LG36", "LG38", "LG4", "LG48", "LG5", 
"LG60", "LG7", "LSP010", "LSP020", "LSP030", "LSP040", "LSP050", 
"LSP060", "LSP070", "LSP080", "LSP089", "LSP100", "LSP110", "LSP120", 
"LSP130", "LSP140", "LSP150", "LSP160", "LSP165", "ST-2LG0", 
"ST-2LG100", "ST-2LG120", "ST-2LG140", "ST-2LG160", "ST-2LG190", 
"ST-2LG40", "ST-2LG60", "ST-2LG80", "T3LB11.301", "T3LB12.05", 
"T3LB12.844", "T3LB13.87", "T3LB14.51", "T3LB14.63", "T3LB15.321", 
"T3LB15.59", "T3LB15.95", "T3LB16.69", "T3LB18.226", "T3LB19.762", 
"T3LB21.078", "T3LB26.256", "T3LB28.57", "T3LB28.84", "T3LB29.03", 
"T3LB31.056", "T3LB31.365", "T3LB7.008", "T3LB7.18", "T3LB7.303", 
"T3LB7.5", "T3LB7.9", "T3LB8.73", "T3LB9.45", "WAP 0 ST-2", "WAP 10 ST-2", 
"WAP 110 ST1", "WAP 120 ST-1", "WAP 122 ST-1", "WAP 125 ST1", 
"WAP 130 ST1", "WAP 135 ST-1", "WAP 140 ST-1", "WAP 144 ST-1", 
"WAP 150 ST-1 ", "WAP 155 ST-1", "WAP 159 ST1", "WAP 160 ST-1", 
"WAP 170 ST-1", "WAP 175 ST 1", "WAP 180 ST-1", "WAP 190 ST-1", 
"WAP 200 ST-1", "WAP 210 ST-1", "WAP 230 ST-1", "WAP 240 ST-1", 
"WAP 25 ST-2", "WAP 40 ST-2", "WAP 45 ST-2", "WAP 5  ST-2", "WAP 50 ST-2", 
"WAP 55 ST-2", "WAP 60 ST-1", "WAP 60 ST-2"), class = "factor"), 
    T.salsa = c(44.4, 75.4, 68, 51.9, 56, 0), H.wilberti = c(9.4, 
    1.8, 8.2, 10.3, 28.8, 0), Textularia = c(0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), T.irregularis = c(0, 3.6, 2.5, 0, 0.4, 0), P.ipohalina = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), J.macrescens = c(5.4, 17.4, 7.4, 13.4, 6.6, 
    45.5), T.inflata = c(40.4, 1.8, 7.4, 24.4, 8.2, 53), S.lobata = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), M.fusca = c(0, 0, 6.6, 0, 0, 1.5), A.agglutinans = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), A.exiguus = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), P.hyperhalina = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), H.germanica = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Quinqueloculina = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Elphidium = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SWLI = c(190.4972376, 
    190.3867403, 190.2762431, 188.3977901, 186.8508287, 185.4143646
    ), Site = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Kudos for using `dput()` to provide the data but it would be more helpful if you went the extra step and provided the code that assigns these with the correct object names so your code can be run and it's not left to users to guess which data belongs to which object name.

Comment: Never do something like `colour=regforamcountsall$SWLI`. There is no guaranty that ggplot2 will preserve the order of `data.scores`. You should add `SWLI` to `data.scores`. `$` should never be used within `aes`.

Comment: Oh I didn't know this - I just assumed it knew to keep the same order, thanks for the tip

Comment: Sorry i've added it now

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you’re after is [`scale_shape`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_shape.html). Unfortunately I don’t understand how to parametrise `scale_shape` with a custom palette<sup>1</sup> — but `scale_shape` is just a thin wrapper around `discrete_scale`, and you can instead use that directly:

```
ggplot(…) +
    discrete_scale('shape', 'shape_d', function (n) (15 : 25)[seq_len(n)])
```

The last argument to `discrete_scale` specifies a palette function which, given a number of discrete groups `n`, returns a vector of `n` different shapes.

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course we could set `breaks` to a named vector, but there’s no reason for us to have to specify the names here, we simply want to provide the possible values (i.e. the “palette”).

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be [an old bug](https://ggplot2.narkive.com/osdDTgJO/trouble-with-scale-shape-manual) in passing a palette function through `scale_shape_discrete`. So, this is a bit more complicated than usual:

```
#based on example in help("scale_shape")
dsmall <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 100), ]

ggplot(dsmall, aes(carat, price, shape = cut, fill = factor(clarity))) + 
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  discrete_scale("shape", "shape", palette=function(n) {
    stopifnot("more than 5 shapes not supported" = n <= 5)
    20 + seq_len(n)
    }) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21)))
```

[image: resulting plot]